# Computing $\gcd of\left(\left(5\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{7}63^i\right)^{10},~135^{135}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

How does one solve these type of some without using calculator?

Comment: One needs calculator if unable to factorize the numbers $63$ and $135$ .

Comment: @PVanchinathan This exercise is for non calculator

Comment: My comment was rhetorical! If I have to explain it further, I meant "no need  for calculator, factorize those numbers 63 and 135 yourself with paper and pencil". Then no hardwork is needed with calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\gcd((5\prod_{i = 1}^7 63^i)^{10},135^{135}) & = \gcd((5^{10}(63^{1+2+\dots+7})^{10},135^{135}) \\
& = \gcd(5^{10}63^{28\times 10},(5\times 27)^{5\times 27}) \\
& = \gcd(5^{10}(3\times 3\times 7)^{280},5^{5\times 3^3}3^{3\times 5\times 3^3}) \\
& = 5^{10}\times 3^{135\times 3}
\end{align*}